# Ayuda con PDO y POO en PHP, me da error 500

Tags: php, pdo

No logro hacer que PDO funcione en un API de PĤP que estoy creando y no entiendo la razon

Aca dejo un poco de mi codigo

La ruta a la que entro es `http://localhost/public/api/order`, la cual me ejecuta el siguiente codigo, el cual me ejecuta el autoload de las clases de mi proyecto, y me dirige la ruta hacia la funcion, esto trabaja bien, no hay problema aca

#### public/index.php

```
<?php

    define("PROJECTPATH", dirname(__DIR__));

    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
       $filename = PROJECTPATH . "/$class.php";
       $filename_real = str_replace(['/',"\\"],DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$filename);
       include_once $filename_real; 
    });

    use Core\Route;
    Route::get('/order', 'UserController@index');
```

Luego, ejecuta el metodo `index` de `UserController` donde llamo al Modelo `App\User` y su metodo `find`

#### App/Http/Controller/UserController.php

```
<?php 
    namespace App\Http\Controller;
    use App\User;
    class UserController  {
        function index() {
            print_r(User::find(1));
        }
    }
```

El siguiente es el modelo de User que extiende la clase Model

#### App/User.php

```
<?php 
    namespace App;

    use Core\Model;

    class User extends Model {

        public $fillable = [
            'username', 'password',
        ];
        public $hidden = [
            'password',
        ];
    }
```

#### Core/Model.php

```
<?php 
    namespace Core;

    use Core\DB;

    class Model extends DB {

        public static function find($id) {
            return $this->$Conn;
        }
    }
```

y por ultimo, mi clase de conexion a la base de datos

#### Core/DB.php (antes Database.php)

```
<?php
namespace Core;

class DB {
   public $Conn;
   function __construct() {
        $this->Conn = $this->connect('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=siccas', "root", "root");
   }
   function connect($driver, $user, $pass){
        try {
            $connection = new PDO($driver, $user, $pass);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print_r($e->getMessage());
            die();
        }   
        return $connection;
    }
}
```

Este es el error en el log

`[Sun Jul 29 20:48:57.842655 2018] [:error] [pid 26386] [client ::1:47265] PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/html/Core/Model.php on line 9`

ignoren si falta las llaves de apertura de PHP, lo omiti para que el codigo se pudiera visualizar aca, gracias de antemano

Comment: la clave del usuario root si es root? por defecto es vacia...

Comment: es root tal cual

Comment: Pero ¿cómo usas tu código? ¿dónde es el error?  En estos casos conviene revisar el log de errores, el cual te dirá dónde está el error específicamente y cuál es la causa del mismo.

Comment: añadiendo `error_reporting(E_ALL);` al script que reporta?

Comment: No tengo un log de errores o por lo menos, no se donde encontrarlo en linux ubuntu. Por otra parte, solo me da error 500, la pagina nisiquiera se muestra ya que solo muestra una predeterminada del navegador

Comment: El error 500 ocurre generalmente cuando hay algún error en el código PHP, como errores de sintaxis por ejemplo. Generalmente hay un archivo llamado `error_log` (o un nombre parecido)  en la carpeta donde está el script o archivo que da error.

Comment: acabo de revisar el log y este es el error que me da

Comment: [Sun Jul 29 20:48:57.842655 2018] [:error] [pid 26386] [client ::1:47265] PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/html/Core/Model.php on line 9

Comment: Conviene que ese error esté en la pregunta, no en un comentario, pues es esencial para encontrar una solución... Admito que no me sé manejar con los espacios de nombre... pero ¿dónde creas una instancia de la clase `Database` para luego poder usarla en `Model`?  La organización que presentas me parece algo confusa y no sé si es debido a que no entiendo lo de los espacios de nombre. Al querer usar `print_r($this->Conn);`   ¿de qué manera hiciste disponible una instancia de `Database` para poder usarla?

Comment: la clase Database extiende de la clase Model, por lo que su constructor automaticamente se ejecuta al hacer una instancia de la clase Model

Comment: ¿Y dónde creas la instancia de la clase `Model`?

Comment: voy a hacer una edicion de mi pregunta donde explicare mejor el flujo

Comment: ¿Si lo pones así da error: `print_r(parent::Conn);`?

Comment: prueba definir `public static $conn` en la clase padre

Comment: He probado tu código tal cual con las clases en un mismo archivo y creando una instancia: `$m=new Model();`, luego un `var_dump($m);` me muestra la propiedad `Conn` (yo puse una cadena de prueba solamente no una conexión a PDO)... y no me da ningún problema. Me da que el error se debe a los dichosos espacios de nombre que tienes o a que lo archivos no están bien organizados en las carpetas donde tienen que estar.

Comment: ya edite la pregunta. Cuando hago estatica la variable `$Conn` no me genera error 500 pero de igual manera, no me devuelve el objeto de PDO, me devuelve `null`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema de conflicto entre `static` y no `static`.  Quieres usar actualmente la conexión desde un método `static` de la clase hija `Model` haciendo esto:

```
    public static function find($id) {
        return $this->$Conn;
    }
```

pero el miembro `Conn` no puede ser accedido desde ese contexto estático porque él no es estático en la clase padre.

Dos soluciones son posibles:

### Solución 1:

Dejar la clase `Database` tal cual la tienes ahora:

```
class Database {
   public $Conn;
   function __construct() {
        $this->Conn = $this->connect('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=siccas', "root", "root");
   }
   function connect($driver, $user, $pass){
        try {
            $connection = new PDO($driver, $user, $pass);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print_r($e->getMessage());
            die();
        }   
        return $connection;
    }
}
```

Declarar el método `find` como no estático, entonces podrás acceder al miembro `Conn` de la clase padre sin problemas mediante `$this`:

```
    public function find($id){
        print_r($this->Conn);
    }
```

---

### Solución 2:

Replantear la clase `Database`:

- declarando `$Conn` como `static`;
- asignando el valor de `$Conn` de este modo `self::$Conn = $this->connect(...parámetros...);` en el constructor.

La clase quedaría así:

```
class Database {
   public  static $Conn;

   function __construct() {

        self::$Conn = $this->connect('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=siccas', "root", "root");
   }

   function connect(){
        try {
            $connection = new PDO($driver, $user, $pass);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print_r($e->getMessage());
            die();
        }   
        return $connection;
    }

}
```

Y en `Model` también tendría que haber cambios:

```
class Model extends Database {

    public static function find($id) {
        print_r(parent::$Conn); // Solo quiero ver que tiene la variable de conexion
    }

}
```

Nótese que `$Conn` es usada invocando al padre `parent` y poniendo el signo `$` delante.

Si `find` es `static` esto implicará que deberá llamarse usando `::` desde la instancia de la clase `Model`, algo así más o menos: `$m::find(...);`

> Observa cómo se invocarían los métodos tanto en la solución 1, como en
>   la solución 2, al final de la prueba de concepto, donde está comentado
>   `/*Probando la clase*/`.

---

### Prueba de concepto

Aquí puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMOSTRACIÓN](http://rextester.com/TFEPDF35299)**</kbd> de ambas soluciones. El método sólo imprime `ok` en vez de devolverte la conexión a PDO. Es lo mismo, si conecta bien, te devolverá tu objeto de conexión.

Comment: No es igual, con namespaces funciona muy diferente a como me lo mandas en la demostracion, igual ya logre solucionar el problema por mi cuenta, gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: ¿Cuál fue la solución @AnthonyMedina para que pueda servir a otros?  Aunque me extraña lo que comentas. El motivo del error que estabas teniendo con `$this` era por lo que te digo en la respuesta. ¿Podrías escribir una respuesta? Este sitio tiene también esa finalidad. Gracias.

Comment: Solo no inicie la conexion en el constructor por que no se ejecuta el construtor de la clase Database, le cree un metodo llamado connect que llamo manualmente, no es la solucion que hubiera querido, pero es la que me resulto

Comment: @AnthonyMedina el error original no era ese. El problema se originaba cuando usabas `$this` en la clase `Model`. Te he propuesto dos soluciones basadas en tu mismo código y me extraña que digas que con name spaces funciona muy diferente. Lo dudo, aunque nunca he trabajado con name spaces, no creo que el código PHP en sí cambie porque uses o no name spaces. Era más bien un problema de organización del código, de confusión entre `static` y no `static`. Pero en fin...

Comment: Tal vez, quien sabe

Comment: @AnthonyMedina Si hubieras dejado el código tal y como lo tenías desde el principio, quitando solamente la palabra `static` del método `find` seguro que funcionaría. Y si aplicas la solución 2 con todos los cambios indicados en ella, también seguro que funcionaría. No creo que el uso de name spaces tenga que ver, a no ser que no tengas los archivos bien organizados (y no era el caso, porque el error era del `$this`). Lo probé como lo tenías sin name spaces y me daba el mismo error que a ti. Al corregirlo como está indicado funciona.

Comment: Tal vez puede ser. Lo cierto es que la solución que propones no funcionan ninguno como debiera. Ya había probado lo. De colocar la variable Conn como estática y ciertamente no da error, pero igual no se conecta a PDO porque el constructor de Database no se ejecuta por lo tanto la variable Conn se que null

Comment: Posiblemente erraste en el constructor, no sé si te fijaste que la variable debe asignarse así: `Database::$Conn = $this->connect('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=siccas', "root", "root");` en caso de declararla como `static` o puedes cambiar `self` por `Database`, pues también veo que la clase en realidad se llama `DB`  (en la nueva edición de la pregunta). Y si es estática, también cambia la forma de llamarla desde la instancia de la clase (se deben usar los dos puntos, algo así: `$m::find(1);`). Si haces **todos los cambios correctamente** no devolvería `NULL` seguro, @AnthonyMedina

Comment: Lo hice también de ese modo creeme. Lo intenté de todos los. Modos posibles tanto lo que propones tu como otras soluciones pero en realidsd nunca se ejecuta el constructor, lo. Comprobé haciendo impresión de alertas de javascript en un echo de PHP y nunca llego a ejecutar el. Constructor. De igual. Manera, de repente tengo un poco de sueno, siempre desps de dormir mi mente amanece más clara. Tal vez esa sea la solución, manana voy a releer esta pregunta y mi. Código y veré en qué estaba errando. Gracias por tu ayuda igualmente amigo

Comment: @AnthonyMedina de nada y buen descanso. Con la mente más relajada afloran mejores soluciones. Saludos.